Problem reusing a freed linked list in a while loop
When I ran the code, only the first iteration of the outer loop gives an meaningful output. The total number of outputs are correct, but all remaining outputs other than the first one prints "-", which means 'findWord' outputs NULL. Assuming all header files needed are included properly, how can I fix this?
I have a linked list implemented as:
typedef struct Node{
    char* word;
    int freq;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* head;

}LL;

LL* createLL(){
  LL* list = malloc(sizeof(LL));
  if (list) {
    list->head = NULL;
  }
  return list;
}

and freed using:
void destroyLL(LL* list){
  
  if(list == NULL || list -> head == NULL){
    return;
  }

  Node* current = list->head;
  Node* next;

  while(current != NULL){
    next = current->next;
    free(current->word);
    free(current);
    current = next; 
  }
  list->head = NULL;
  free(list);
}

the way I add nodes into the list is:
void add_Node(LL* list, char* word, int freq){
  Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  /*
  if(newNode == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "not able to create node\n");
    return;
  }
  */
  newNode->word = strdup(word);
  /*
  if(newNode->word == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "can't allocate mem for word\n");
    free(newNode);
    return;
  }
  */
  newNode -> freq = freq;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  if(list->head == NULL){
    list -> head = newNode;
  }
  else{
    Node* current = list->head;
    while(current->next != NULL){
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
  }
  //return newNode;
}

void addFreq(LL* list, char* word){
  /*
  if(word == NULL){
    return;
  }
  */
  Node* current = list->head;
  while(current != NULL){
    if(strcmp(current->word, word) == 0){
      current->freq++;
      return;
    }

    current = current->next;
  }
  add_Node(list, word, 1);
}

my main function looks like:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE* input;

  //LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
  //list->head = NULL;  

    char *shake = /*...*/ //the name of a file  
    FILE* shake_txt = fopen(shake, "r");
    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  
  char target[100];
  int length;
  int target_freq;
  
  

  while(fgets(target, sizeof(target), input) != NULL){   //gets imputs from a file with inputs on each line
    //LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
    //list->head = NULL;
    LL* list = createLL();

    if(sscanf(target, "%d %d", &length, &target_freq)==2){
      
      char word[100];
        while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), shake_txt) != NULL){ //shake_txt has a word on each line, this loop goes through each line and adds the word to the linked list if it is the input length
          if(strlen(word) == length+1){
          addFreq(list, word);
        }
      }
      sortLL(list); //assume nothing goes wrong here

      findWord(list, target_freq)==NULL? printf("-\n"):  printf("%s", findWord(list, target_freq)); finds the target_freq-th node and returns the word
      
      if(findWord(list, target_freq)==NULL){ //this is used for debugging, ignore it
        printLL(list);
      }
      
    }
    destroyLL(list); //frees the linked list so it can be used in the next iteration

  }
  //assume all files are closed properly
}

After some testing I found out that after the first iteration of the outer loop, there is nothing in the linked list itself. 'addFreq' works, and destroyLL works too. This is what I got after running valgrind if it helps:
==165== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==165== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==165== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==165== Command: ./Bard simple-input.txt
==165== 
father
-
-
-   //<-- only the last line should be a "-" others should be words i.e."father"
-
-
==165== 
==165== HEAP SUMMARY:
==165==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==165==   total heap usage: 9,705 allocs, 9,705 frees, 165,472 bytes allocated
==165== 
==165== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==165== 
==165== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==165== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


What does the computer say if you tell it to print all the words in the linked list?

@user253751 it would print all words in the linked list and all of them have the same length. At least that is what happens in the first iteration.

The problem has nothing to do with your linked list in particular.  It is that on the first iteration of the outer loop, you read file shake_txt all the way to its end, after which there is nothing more for the subsequent iterations to read.
You must rewind(shake_txt) or fseek(shake_txt, 0, SEEK_SET) (or open it anew) before you can take another pass through the file.

@The-coder-E A mistake like this is easy to make, but also easy to catch if you use a debugger. Lots of new programmers seem hesitant to learn to use a debugger, but investing an hour or two early in your programming journey will pay dividends for a long time to come.
